# Light switches On in the Off position and Vice Versa

Tags: electrical, switch

Good Morning,

I have a Levitron Two Position switch, which switches on in the OFF position.

I know a cheap fix is to just turn the switch around, but there is a label at the bottom of the switch that says says Levitron and it won't look good upside down.

I tried to switch the wires on the terminal and it still only turns on in the OFF position.

Before there was an old switch which I took out and replaced with the new two position Levitron switch after I replaced it, ALL THE SWITCHES IN THE HOUSE NOW ONLY WORK IN THE OFF POSITION.

I tried hard to switch the wires around but to no avail.

I made a wiring diagram for your convenience:

- There are three entry points into the box:  From the Top, Top Left, and Bottom Left (denoted by the arrows)
- I didn't put the green wire in the diagram because the switch works without it (I am testing it with the old switch)
- The B marrett has a red and black wire was not connected to the switch and I am not sure where it originates from.

[image: Outlet Box]
[image: Wiring Diagram]

Comment: What is a "B marrett"? Also, the green pigtail (which is the grounding wire) from the switch should _NOT_ be connected to the neutrals (the white & grey wires). It should be connected via a 10-32 screw to the appropriate hole in the back of the metal junction box. Leaving it connected creates a dangerous situation here and at other switches & fixtures.

Comment: How do you define "off position"?  When you say "2 position switch" I assume you mean it's either on or off.  If that's the case then there is no way to change what position is on or off.

Comment: Is there a _brass_ screw on the other side of the switch? If so, you have a 3-way switch.

Comment: We can help but need more info: did you wire this kind switch at other places in the house too? And we need pictures from the back and other side. It seems wrong and dangerous as wired in the picture, but hard to tell from the angle.

Comment: You have a lot of wires and you are connecting them without understanding which is the line hot (always hot), which is switched hot, which might be neutrals, which might be ground. Do you have a voltage tester? Is this switch one of a pair of switches which controls a light or set of lights?

Comment: Looks to me like non standard and possibly unsafe wiring that might require an expert to correct. There are experts here but they would need a picture of the inside of the box with better lighting.

Comment: I'll reply to all comments here:          1. I labelled the marrett "b", its hidden inside the box not visible in the photo.                                                            2.  There is no brass screw ( its single pole)  3.  Yes I have a multimeter, it just controls one light - but there are wires in the box that if you disconnect them results in the kitchen light not working  4. I'll take a better picture when I'm there on Friday.

Comment: With your multimeter in continuity/resistance setting (beep or Ohm measurement) you can confirm that your single pole switch is on in one position and off in the other, and unfortunately there is no re-wiring that would change the orientation. Of course, for this test you must entirely unwire the switch from the box. Almost by universal convention up is on and down is off, in northern as well as southern hemisphere.

Comment: I'll bite... What is "marrett"? Maybe it's a wiring term that I'm just not familiar with...

Comment: @FreeMan "Marrette" is a Twist-on wire connector, named after the brand and inventor, and is now a common name for the connector regardless brand

Comment: Thanks, @P2000 like the difference between Kleenex™, kleenex, and tissue. Got it. I'd have just called it a "wire nut". #TIL

Comment: @FreeMan -- it's a regional thing... in California now and none of my electricians have ever heard of a marrett. Canada is a different world sometimes.

Comment: Good answer below, but when you get into the box with your multimeter, check to see if you can make ~240v with any two wires. If so, you have a legit mess on your hands. (And extra reason to be cautious, as flipping one breaker isn't necessarily going to save your bacon.)

Answer (score 5):

Standard colors are:

- Neutral: White or gray
- Safety Ground: Green, yellow w/ green stripe, bare, or the shell of non-flexing metal conduit, and metal boxes.
- Hot: all other colors.

If a multi-wire cable is used, the white can be marked with hot-color tape and used as a hot. That does not apply in conduit. Conduits need 1 neutral per circuit and it must be white or gray.

### Ground NEVER EVER Goes to anything else

Safety grounds, always and only green, yellow/green or bare, **are never wired to any other conductor. Period. End of subject.**  I don't how how in the bloody green blazes a green wire came to go from the switch's green screw to the neutral bundle, but **fire the guy who did that**.  That person lacks the basic knowledge required not to kill somebody.

If that's you, quit and hire a pro. Seriously, *what the heck*.

### STOP EXPERIMENTING

You've dug yourself an irrecoverable hole because your response to "it doesn't work" was to "try random stuff".  By "random" I mean you don't have *knowledge* of what it does.

What will happen when you hit a combination that works (or works "good enough"?  You stop.  Trouble is, there are many combinations which will work *and will kill you*.

When you are stuck, stop and collect more information.  I know you're not doing that because of the ground wire in the neutral bundle, which is a "101" blunder.

### It may be too late

Unfortunately, you seem to have relied on a notion that no matter how scrambled you make it, there are standard color-codes or groupings that will tell a remote expert how to fix it. That belief is false, unfortunately.  There are no color codes other than what I said at the top.  The only way electricians tell *the next electrician* the meanings of the wires is by **how things are arranged currently**.

Now, the only path is a great deal of on-site  iterative testing, which is too far beyond your skill-set to be achievable, even with support of people online.  I think the option available to you is to call a pro... unless you took good photos of the starting condition that was known-working.

Comment: I took the green wire from neutral.

Comment: I have a diploma in auto electrics, so it's not too beyond my  skill set.                                                                 I think power is coming directly to the box since the switch before it is in the kitchen and it only has two  wires.